# Does the "the theory of poker applied to no limit" cover all the contents in "The Theory of Poker" both by David Sklansky?

Tags: poker-theory, books

I haven't read the "The Theory of Poker" and am planning to start reading. Then I found the newest book "the theory of poker applied to no limit". So I am wondering which one should I start? I play usually sit&go and no limit cash games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case , I'm currently reading "the theory of poker" and I can tell that the book is really changing my way to think as a poker player. In the other hand, I can't tell you anything about the other version. The only negative aspect of the book I'm reading is that most of the examples to illustrate the concepts explained are of 7 cards stud and not texas hold'em or omaha but still is understandable. I totally recomend you to read it.

Comment: How does this answer the question, and why was it accepted as the answer?

Comment: If you have a better answer you can share it with us!

Answer (score 0):

I have not read it myself yet (I will update if I do), but it says in the book description that it contains summaries of the original's points, but are not as thorough.

Here's an except from [an Amazon reviewer](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/RT9E9JI4KVFRP/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=1880685612):

> In a lot of sections he decides to tell the reader to read his other book for in depth study when he decides not to tell the reader the complete picture. He assumes a lot of people read the first book and tells them frequently enough to go back to it making it bothersome considering the first book was for limit.